# Given a Global JavaScript function, how to export to a React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I have the following React component:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Gauge from "./libs/svg-gauge";

const Container = styled.div``;

class MyGauge extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.renderGauge(this.props);
  };

  renderGauge = () => {
    // HERE is the issue - Gauge is not defined
    console.log(Gauge);
    if (!this.gauge) {
      this.gauge = Gauge(this.gaugeEl, {});
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <RatingGaugeItem
          ref={el => {
            this.gaugeEl = el;
          }}
        />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default MyGauge;
```

Where `import Gauge from "./libs/svg-gauge";` is this file: https://github.com/naikus/svg-gauge/blob/master/src/gauge.js

The issue I'm having after updating storybook to `"@storybook/react": "5.1.7",` is that while this works fine within my react web app, in storybook, I'm getting the following error:

```
Object(...) is not a function
```

And it's because Gauge is no defined. Note the `console.log(Gauge);` --- that is not finding Gauge. Am I importing the `gauge.js` file incorrectly, or perhaps I need to update the `gauge.js` file to export version populate the Gauge in the global scope?

Comment: Longshot: try installing the gauge npm package so it ends up in node_modules instead. Maybe you end up in a scenario where it gets weird with the relative path

Comment: I'm not using the package as I need to customize the library.

Comment: I have `svg-gauge.js` saved locally which is what is here "./libs/svg-gauge"